# AndroidStudio ActionBar not showing in editor and screen size does not match phone

Tags: android-studio

I'm getting into Android Studio but i'm stuck at the moment. I've made a basic app and deployed it to my phone. It shows the AppBar (top bar) on my phone, but not in the editor.

I'm using `Theme.AppCompat.Light` in the manifest, which has an ActionBar. I've also selected it in the editor. No action bar is showing up.

[image: Android studio]

It does show up on the phone.

Also i have the dimensions set to 1920x1080, which matches my phone. Though, the top of the screen in the editor falls off the top of the phone. Does this have to do with the ActionBar, bottom menu buttons and top menu bar?

As you can see the elements are at the top of the screen while they are not in the editor.

[image: Phone]

How do i get the ActionBar to show up in the editor and how do i get the dimensions right? Thank you.

Comment: Use AppTheme instead. And remember that the theme you pick in the editor isn't necessarily representative for the theme used for the layout itself

Comment: I know and i've tried AppTheme also. There's no bar shown in the editor then either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the preview, you need to enable layout decoration showing :
**First, open this menu:**

[image]
**Now press "show layout decorations"**
[image]

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. There's still more space shown above the elements in the editor compared to the phone, though. Any thoughts on that? The resolution matches.

Comment: do you mean space from your layout to your action bar?

Comment: Yes. There's a gap between "TestApp" in the editor thats not there on the phone.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe try to refresh the layout preview? maybe this can help

Comment: No luck there, unfortunately.

Comment: What are the odds that you have `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` attribute? if so try to remove it or set it to false

Comment: I do not have it no. Did a "search everywhere" but, negative.